# Quasi-components on a product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space

In a space $X$, we define $x\sim y$ if there is no descomposition of $X$ into two disjoint open sets, one which contains $x$ and the other $y$ (the equivalence classes are called quasi-components).

The statement is:

If $x_1\sim x_2$ in $X$ and $y_1\sim y_2$ in $Y$ then $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)$ in $X\times Y$. Or equivalently, $(x_1,y_1)\nsim (x_2,y_2)$ implies $x_1\nsim x_2$ or $y_1\nsim y_2$.

If $(x_1,y_1)\nsim (x_2,y_2)$, there would be $A,B$ open in $X\times Y$ such that $X\times Y=A\cup B, A\cap B= \emptyset$ and $(x_1,y_1)\in A$ and $(x_2,y_2)\in B$.

How can I show $x_1\nsim x_2$ or $y_1\nsim y_2$? Any hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Insert a step in between. Show $(x_1,y_1) \sim \;? \sim (x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't get it. That statement is not a question, but a true proposition I guess.

Comment: Right. But to show $(x_1 \sim x_2 \land y_1 \sim y_2) \implies (x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2)$ or equivalently $(x_1,y_1) \nsim (x_2,y_2) \implies (x_1 \nsim x_2 \lor y_1 \nsim y_2)$, it is convenient to use an intermediate point "between" $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer edited. Is that what you said?

Comment: Do you remember the "rectangular"method from proving how components in a product are products of components?

Comment: @Daron I don't think so. I don't know what "rectangular" mean to say.

Comment: @Tanius You can read the proof of this statement in "Topology II" by Kazimierz Kuratowski.